# Data not adding to SQL Server 2008 using ASP.net & VB as code behind file

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I've looked around StackOverflow and also a number of other websites, I found some code to put this together:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Partial Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

  Dim sqlConnection As SqlConnection
  Dim sqlCommand As SqlCommand
  Dim sqlString, iName, iDescription As String
  Dim iQuantity As Integer
  Dim iPrice As Decimal

  Protected Sub cmdAddStock_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
  Handles cmdAddStock.Click

    iName = txtItemName.Text
    iDescription = txtDescription.Text
    iQuantity = txtQuantity.Text
    iPrice = txtPrice.Text

    Using myConnection As New SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=BBBLeeds;
    Trusted_Connection=True")
        myConnection.Open()

        sqlCommand = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblItem(ItemName, Description, 
        Price, Stock) values('" + iName + "','" + iDescription + "','" + iPrice + 
        "','" + iQuantity + "')")

        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        myConnection.Close()
        Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl, True)
    End Using
End Sub
End Class
```

The error which comes back is as follows:

"Conversion from string "INSERT INTO tblItem(ItemName, De" to type 'Double' is not valid."

This is the data structure with SQL:

http://i23.photobucket.com/albums/b368/Damo115/Untitled.png

Thanks for any advice you can provide.

Comment: Please look into using SQL parameters to send your parameters. It will save a lot of hassle. And the string concatenation operator in VB.NET is `&`, not `+`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to do this, this will avoid any sql injections and you don't have to deal with concatenation and adding quotes around values.

In your table `price` is `money` datatype and `Stock` is `int` but you are sending values as string by adding single quotes around them.

```
sqlCommand = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblItem(ItemName, Description, 
        Price, Stock) values(@item,@descr,@price,@stock)")

sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item",iName)
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@descr",iDescription)
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price",iPrice)
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stock",iQuantity)

sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: This is part the answer I am looking for, but I now have the problem where I get the error:

"ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized."

Although there are answers for this, no matter what I have tried I still get the same problem being thrown back.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You pass in a string parameter (txtPrice.Text) as a number (the db column Price is a number). You need to covert your string to the number first.

Answer (score -1):

You should be using the `&` operator rather than the `+` operator to concatenate strings

```
sqlCommand = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblItem(ItemName, Description, 
        Price, Stock) values('" & iName & "','" & iDescription & "','" + iPrice & 
        "','" & iQuantity & "')")
```

Comment: Please explain the downvote. This answers the question specifically.

Comment: Sorry this throws back the same problem as before. Something a friend told me earlier, whether I put the variable as a String or something similar in VB it will try inputting the data from VB as a an integer or double (latter being the case) into SQL and because of this it goes into debug mode. However, the answer specified fixes the main problem but unfortunately brings up another.

Thanks for the help though, appreciate you trying. Also, I apologize but it wasn't me who down voted you (that I am aware of).

Comment: Ahhh... I understand... I think the best answer is the one you've accepted :-D Thanks for the reply!